# Can an alternating series diverge to $\pm\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n n!$$

The series cannot converge because it doesn't satisfy the vanishing condition:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}(-1)^nn! \neq 0$$

My question is: can the series diverge to $\pm\infty$? I have tried to answer the question by studying the sequence of partial sums

$$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kk!$$

hoping to prove that the sign of $\{s_n\}$ is itself alternating, which would prove that the original series cannot diverge to $\pm \infty$. However, I don't know how to prove that

$$n! \geq |s_{n-1}|, \forall n$$

Am I on the right path? Is my conjecture true? I have tried googling an answer but I haven't found anything useful, only a bunch of warning about errouneus applications of the Leibniz test.
I would be very grateful I you could help me.

Comment: You need to define what it means to diverge to $\pm \infty$ because it is not normally defined.  It sounds like you mean there is a subsequence converging to $+\infty$ and a subsequence converging to $-\infty$.  Maybe you need to require that the two subsequences are complementary so there are no small values far out.  If your definition is as I suggested, your sequence meets it.

Comment: By "divergence to $\pm\infty$", I mean
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}s_n = \pm\infty$$
These are the words used in Italian, which is my native language. Is there a better way to express the same concept in English?

Comment: Your words are fine.  As written, your equation doesn't mean anything because we don't have a definition for it.  You need to provide that definition.  If you remove the $\pm$ sign, we have a definition:  For any $M \gt 0,$ there is an $n$ such that $s_n \gt M$, essentially that the elements of the sequence get very large and never get small.  I was trying to extend that in a reasonable way to cover your case.  I think there is a reasonable notion here.  If it proves useful, the definition will be accepted and become standard.

Comment: I understand. I will be as precise as possible. In my mind, the symbol $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}s_n = \pm\infty$$ means $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}s_n = +\infty \lor \lim_{n \to +\infty}s_n = -\infty.$$

Comment: I haven't been more specific in the orginal post because this is standard notation in my university and according to a couple of the textbooks we study on. I guess different environments use different notation. Thanks for the help and adivice.

Comment: That is also a fine definition of the term.  It requires that the limit exist, which is not true for the sequence $s_n$.  For your question at the end, yes it is true that each factorial is greater than the sum of all the smaller ones except for $1,2$.  You can prove it by induction.  It is true for $3$, and $(n+1)!=(n+1)n! \gt 2(n! )\gt n!+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, an alternating sum that diverges can diverge to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Take the sums

$$
1-1+2-1+3-1+4-1+5-1+\cdots
$$ and
$$
1-1+1-2+1-3+1-4+1-5+\cdots
$$
for examples of either.

---

Your sum, however, does not diverge to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ (i.e., it does not have a generalized limit). Since you already know that the sequence does not converge, it is sufficient to additionally show that the sequence of partial sums has an alternating sign*. This can easily be proven as it follows from the fact that, for every $n\geq 2$, we have $n! > \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k!$**.

Note that it is not required to show that it is also unbounded. For example, the alternating sum
$$1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots$$ does **not** have an unbounded sequence of partial sums, yet it still diverges.

---

* This is because if the series does not converge, then you know the sequence of partial sums can either diverge to $\infty$, to $-\infty$, or neither. If you show the sequence of partial sums has alternating sign, then it cannot diverge to $\infty$ (because it goes below $0$ infinitely many times) and it cannot diverge to $-\infty$ (because it goes above $0$ infinitely many times).

** This is very simple to show, since
$$
n! = n\cdot (n-1)! > \sum_{k=1}^n (n-1)! >\sum_{k=1}^n k! > \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k!$$

Comment: Just to be pedantic: It is in general not enough that the sequence of partial sums has alternating signs - it could still a priori converge to zero. Adding the fact that the partial sums are "discrete", i.e. always whole numbers, ensures that we never get close to zero though.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Of course, but the idea was that we already know the sequence does not converge. We know this because the summands to not converge to $0$.

Comment: Any series that is not convergent to a finite limit is divergent. I think it is not a good idea to say a divergent series "converges to $\infty$", as that just confuses the concept of convergence. The OP used "diverge to $\infty$" which is better, though their concept of "diverge to $\pm \infty$" is unclear.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I agree, "diverge to $\infty$ is better. I changed my post. The thing is that in my language, we use the phrase "converge to $\infty$" to describe that. It sounds confusing, but it is possible, I guarantee it, to use it correctly :)

Comment: Thanks, can you link any source with a proof of the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k! < n!$ for all $n>4$?

Comment: @francescoriccardocrescenzi I added the argument into my answer. It's actually true for all $n\geq 2$ :).

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $(s_{2n})_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$ increases while $(s_{2n+1})_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$ decreases. These prevents $s_n$ from converging to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.